# Change Viewpager2 fragment from child fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Main fragment/ViewPager fragment inside the Main Activity and the Main Fragment has the `Viewpager2` where I add child fragments into `ViewPager` via Adapter. Earlier I had a method in Main Activity (Which also had view pager)

```
public void ChangeFragment_ViewPager(int position, boolean outside) {
        if (viewPager!=null){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }    
    }
```

This method easily changes the fragment when I call from any child fragment of viewpager but since I shifted the viewpager to the Main fragment, my viewpager always comes out null from child.

```
 MainFragment.newInstance().ChangeFragment_ViewPager(0, false);
```

The Main Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager2 viewPager;
    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.Navigation_Drawer_ViewPager);
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    }

   
    public void ChangeFragment_ViewPager(int position, boolean outside) {
        if (viewPager!=null){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

    }
```

Tab Adapter

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    String TAG="###TAB ADAPTER###";

    public TabAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Fragment 1");
                return FriendsList.newInstance();
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "Fragment 2");
                return PPL_main.newInstance();
        }
        return FriendsList.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

How can I change the fragment from any ViewPager's child fragment?

Comment: Can you share how to due make MainFragment transaction in the supportManager?

Comment: @Zain I updated the question with the tabapater i am using. Please check

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear; I mean how do you add the mainFragment in the main activity .. Do you add it in the layout or through supportManager .. something like https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions

Comment: @Zain `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,MainFragment.class,null)
                    .commit();`

Comment: @Zain It is added by support manager like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `MainFragment.newInstance().ChangeFragment_ViewPager(0,false);`

This line of code instantiates a brand new instance of `MainFragment`; and therefore you found a null `ViewPager`.

Instead of that, the current instance exist in the fragment manager is required or simply use `requireParentFragment()` from the `ViewPager` child page fragment to get the `MainFragment` that hosts the `ViewPager`:

```
((MainFragment) requireParentFragment()).ChangeFragment_ViewPager(0, false);
```

Comment: Thanks and it's really quick solution.but i think `getsupportfragmentmanager` is the right option to start first fragment